# MpChart Combined chart auto scroll option

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MP chart lib for my android project. I am creating CombinedChart(Bar chart & Line chart) with negative values. Charts is coming up, But when I increase the number of values across X axis, bar width decreases in order to accommodate the values.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT0oO.png)

How can I include values along X axis without shrinking the bar width and when graph comes up user can scroll horizontally to see all the values.

I am setting

Comment: Hi did you manage this, Mine doesnt work as well

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work :

```
combinedChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(10);
```

give your number instead of ten